# How to determine why a Java program is not accepting 7 console inputs?

Tags: java

I have an application where you are supposed to enter 7 integers and then the application is supposed to tell you how many occurrences each number is put in.

Example: if I have 5 6 7 8 8 5 8, then it is supposed to come back that I have two 5's, one 6, one 7, and three 8's.  All I'm getting out of it, however; is the first number i put in, in this case 5, and then it occurs 7 times.  How do I fix this problem?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class U7A1_NumberCount {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final int MAX_INPUT_LENGTH = 7;
    int[] inputArray = new int[MAX_INPUT_LENGTH];
    System.out.print("Please, enter seven integers: ");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    int max = 0;
    int nums = input.nextInt();
    for(int n = 0; n < MAX_INPUT_LENGTH; n++) {
        if(inputArray[n] > max) {
            max = inputArray[n];
        }
    }
    int[] count = new int[max + 1];
    for(int n = 0; n < MAX_INPUT_LENGTH; n++) {
        count[(inputArray[n])]++;
    }

    for(int n = 0; n < count.length; n++) {
        if(count[n] > 0) {
            System.out.println("The number " + nums + " occurs " + count[n] + " times.");
        }
    }
}

}
```

Comment: If you're using something like this, use a `HashBag` (or implement something like a `HashBag` by creating a class backed with a `Map<Object, Integer>` which increments the value for each additional call on the key). Otherwise, you have to create a unique set of the integers and then count each one and create a similar listing afterwards, which is effectively equivalent.

Comment: You call `input.nextInt();` only once, so you only read one number.

Comment: Robert, could you elaborate on that.

Comment: Using a debugger would be helpful. input.nextInt() will return int = 5. The 6 7 8 8 5 8 never get read.

Answer (score 0):

For input of the numbers, I would use something that can take many integers on a single line split by some delimiter. So basically, if the comma is the delimiter,

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
// some prompt here
List<Integer> intList = Stream.of(scan.nextLine().split(','))
    .map(String::trim)
    .map(Integer::new)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Obviously, some more error handling could be useful (e.g. skipping things which cannot be parsed to an integer). You could also change your delimiter to be anything which is not a digit.

Then I would create a `HashBag` (for example, I will be using the implementation in Apache Commons Collections) and print the results with the bag's `toString`.

```
HashBag bag = new HashBag(intList);
System.out.println(bag.toString());
```

Or you could iterate through the `HashBag` to get and print the information you want.

Implementation of a `HashBag`-like object would be trivial: make a class backed with a `HashMap<Object, Integer>` and use some kind of adding method to call an `Object#equals` and if true, increment the value, and if false, create a new key with value 1.

Answer (score 0):

first at all, if you do not understand your code make it more readable ... this avoids a lot of problems simply in the beginning.

according to clean code of robert c. martin try to write down the code as you think about it. (https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clean_Code)

here is one very reduced example to make it not to complicate

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class U7A1_NumberCount {

private static class NumberCount {
    public NumberCount(final int number, final int amount) {
        this.number = number;
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    int amount;
    int number;
}

public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final int MAX_INPUT_LENGTH = 7;
    final int[] userInput = readUserInput(MAX_INPUT_LENGTH);
    final List<NumberCount> count = getNumberCount(userInput);
    printResult(count);
}

private static NumberCount countSingleNumber(final int nr, final int[] userInput) {
    int amount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < userInput.length; i++) {
        if (userInput[i] == nr) {
            amount++;
        }
    }
    return new NumberCount(nr, amount);
}

private static List<NumberCount> getNumberCount(final int[] userInput) {
    final List<NumberCount> result = new LinkedList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < userInput.length; i++) {
        final int nr = userInput[i];
        if (isNumberNotConsideredYet(result, nr)) {
            final NumberCount count = countSingleNumber(nr, userInput);
            result.add(count);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

private static int getUsersChoice(final Scanner scanner) {
    System.out.print("Please, enter a number: ");
    return scanner.nextInt();
}

private static boolean isNumberNotConsideredYet(final List<NumberCount> result, final int nr) {
    return result.stream().noneMatch(count -> count.number == nr);
}

private static void printResult(final List<NumberCount> count) {
    for (final NumberCount nr : count) {
        System.out.println("The number " + nr.number + " occurs " + nr.amount + " times.");
    }
}

private static int[] readUserInput(final int inputAmout) {
    final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    final int[] userInput = new int[inputAmout];
    for (int i = 0; i < userInput.length; i++) {
        userInput[i] = getUsersChoice(scanner);
    }
    scanner.close();
    return userInput;
}

}
```

Comment: maybe you do not get the meaning of "very reduced"

Comment: Your class NumberCount end in about Line 15 or so, leaving the following main homeless. Correct indentation would have prevent that. I guess with 269 reputation, you're able to fix it yourself. Look at this homeless, trailing, curly brace outside of your code block. Have a nice weekend. :)

Comment: in the time you talk about that, you could fix it yourself ... but if it makes you happy :-) i could live on that

Answer (score 0):

Java is object oriented language, so use classess and objects to simplify your code. I would do it like that:

```
public class CountNumbers {

    private Map<Integer,Integer> numbers = new HashMap<>();

    public void addNumber(Integer number){
        Integer howMany =numbers.get(number);
        if( null != howMany){
            howMany++;
        }else{
            howMany=1;
        }
        numbers.put(number,howMany);
    }

    public Map<Integer,Integer> getNumbers(){
        return numbers;
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Majn {

    final static int MAX_INPUT_LENGTH = 7;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CountNumbers countNumbers = new CountNumbers();

        System.out.print("Please, enter seven integers: ");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        for(int i = 0; i< MAX_INPUT_LENGTH; i++) {
            int nums = input.nextInt();
            countNumbers.addNumber(nums);
        }

        for(Integer number: countNumbers.getNumbers().keySet()){
            System.out.format("The number %d occurs %d\n", number, countNumbers.getNumbers().get(number));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> is the first number i put in, in this case 5, and then it occurs 7 times. How do I fix this problem?

You created an array to hold 7 integers, but you didn't utilise it. You only assigned value to another variable:

```
int nums = input.nextInt();
```

If you want to input all 7 inputs into the array, you can prompt the user n times:

```
for(int i=0; i<inputArray.length; i++)
    inputArray[i] = input.nextInt();    //requires user to press enter 7 times
```